# Can bash `locate` command generate numbered results / aliases?

Tags: bash

I want to avoid having to type  or copy-paste a full path.

Ideally, I would like to see and be able to do something like this:

```
$locate test.txt
1 /dir1/test.txt
2 /dir2/test.txt

$ vi !1
```

Comment: I like laziness but please next time write some words more on your question :)

Answer (score 0):

With some tricks:

```
set $(locate text.txt)
i=1 ; while [ "$1" ] ; do echo "\$$i $1" ; i=$(( i + 1 )) ; shift ; done
```

Then you can do `vi $1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write directly

```
  vi $(locate Test | head -n 1)
```

or you can create a bash function that you can call e.g. `p test.txt 3` to have the 3rd line found from locate

```
  p(){ vi $(locate $1 | head -n ${2:-1} | tail -1 ); }
```

If you like the function you can put it in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` file...